# AWS Java SDK error: Unable to load credentials from any of the providers

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-java-sdk

I'm writing a test to see if I can access credentials stored in AWS secrets manager, in Java on my local machine.

I've tested that I have an active session on my machine by running the `aws sts get-caller-identity` command as suggested in the aws docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/setup.html#setup-credentials:%7E:text=aws%20sts%20get%2Dcaller%2Didentity).

I even ran the command `aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id some-id` in intelliJ's terminal to check if I could retrieve the secret value and I was successful.

However when I attempt to get the value using the AWS SDK

```
var client = SecretsManagerClient.builder()
        .region(Region.of(region))
        .build();

var getSecretValueRequest = GetSecretValueRequest.builder()
        .secretId(secretName)
        .build();

var getSecretValueResponse = client.getSecretValue(getSecretValueRequest);
```

It fails with the error:

```
software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Unable to load credentials from any of the providers in the chain AwsCredentialsProviderChain(credentialsProviders=[SystemPropertyCredentialsProvider(), EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider(), WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider(), ProfileCredentialsProvider(profileName=default, profileFile=ProfileFile(profilesAndSectionsMap=[{default=Profile(name=default, properties=[output, sso_session, aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key, region, sso_role_name, sso_account_id])}, {my-sso=Profile(name=my-sso, properties=[sso_region, sso_start_url, sso_registration_scopes])}])), ContainerCredentialsProvider(), InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider()]) : [SystemPropertyCredentialsProvider(): Unable to load credentials from system settings. Access key must be specified either via environment variable (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID) or system property (aws.accessKeyId)., EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider(): Unable to load credentials from system settings. Access key must be specified either via environment variable (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID) or system property (aws.accessKeyId)., WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider(): Either the environment variable AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE or the javaproperty aws.webIdentityTokenFile must be set., ProfileCredentialsProvider(profileName=default, profileFile=ProfileFile(profilesAndSectionsMap=[{default=Profile(name=default, properties=[output, sso_session, aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key, region, sso_role_name, sso_account_id])}, {my-sso=Profile(name=my-sso, properties=[sso_region, sso_start_url, sso_registration_scopes])}])): To use Sso related properties in the 'default' profile, the 'sso' service module must be on the class path., ContainerCredentialsProvider(): Cannot fetch credentials from container - neither AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_FULL_URI or AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI environment variables are set., InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider(): Failed to load credentials from IMDS.]

    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException$BuilderImpl.build(SdkClientException.java:111)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.AwsCredentialsProviderChain.resolveCredentials(AwsCredentialsProviderChain.java:117)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.internal.LazyAwsCredentialsProvider.resolveCredentials(LazyAwsCredentialsProvider.java:45)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.DefaultCredentialsProvider.resolveCredentials(DefaultCredentialsProvider.java:123)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.util.MetricUtils.measureDuration(MetricUtils.java:50)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.internal.authcontext.AwsCredentialsAuthorizationStrategy.resolveCredentials(AwsCredentialsAuthorizationStrategy.java:100)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.internal.authcontext.AwsCredentialsAuthorizationStrategy.addCredentialsToExecutionAttributes(AwsCredentialsAuthorizationStrategy.java:77)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.internal.AwsExecutionContextBuilder.invokeInterceptorsAndCreateExecutionContext(AwsExecutionContextBuilder.java:120)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.client.handler.AwsSyncClientHandler.invokeInterceptorsAndCreateExecutionContext(AwsSyncClientHandler.java:69)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.lambda$execute$1(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:78)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.measureApiCallSuccess(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:179)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.execute(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:76)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.SdkSyncClientHandler.execute(SdkSyncClientHandler.java:45)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.client.handler.AwsSyncClientHandler.execute(AwsSyncClientHandler.java:56)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.services.secretsmanager.DefaultSecretsManagerClient.getSecretValue(DefaultSecretsManagerClient.java:983)
```

Comment: "I've tested that I have an active session on my machine by running the aws sts get-caller-identity" That just tests that you have valid AWS credentials configured in that specific command line console. There is no such thing as having "an active session" on your entire machine. Please include in your questoin how you are specifically providing credentials to the Java process. Also, see the settings retreival order documentation here: I've tested that I have an active session on my machine by running the aws sts get-caller-identity

Comment: Are you sure? As in the official docs that I linked it literally says "To test if you already have an active session, run the following AWS CLI command". I assume it means that you have an sso token that is not expired. The SDK code that I've copied into the question above will execute that retrieval order you're asking me to read about. I only have the default profile set in my aws credentails file and the sso config in the config file. I used aws sso login

Comment: I have no aws system or user environment variables set or aws variables set in java code. Aside from passing in the region.

Comment: Sorry I had a copy/paste error in my original comment. The retrieval order is documented here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/credentials-chain.html And yes I'm sure about how it works. How did you actually configure the AWS CLI tool in your command line console to have permissions to your AWS account so that those AWS CLI commands would work? Without those details I can't tell you how to get the Java AWS SDK to use those same credentials.

Comment: I followed the instructions in the link provided in my question ( https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/setup.html#setup-credentials:%7E:text=aws%20sts%20get%2Dcaller%2Didentity.)

I have the ~/.aws/config as shown in the link above. It also states "you need an active AWS access portal session in order for the SDK to use IAM Identity Center authentication to resolve credentials" and tells us to run the aws sso login command which I did